# How do I specify names for missing commands in the help message generated by optparse-applicative?

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

I am attempting to use Hackage's [optparse-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) package and have a question regarding how to specify a certain aspect of the help message displayed when the program is run with insufficient commands specified.

The following example program illustrates my issue. When run from the command line it takes one of two commands as input. That is, it is intended to be run either as `$ program com1` or `$ program com2`.

```
module Main where

import Options.Applicative
import Data.Semigroup ((<>))

data Command = Com1
             | Com2

com1 :: Parser Command
com1 = subparser $ command "com1" $ info (pure Com1) fullDesc

com2 :: Parser Command
com2 = subparser $ command "com2" $ info (pure Com2) fullDesc

commandParser :: Parser Command
commandParser = com1
            <|> com2

runCommand :: Command -> IO ()
runCommand Com1 = putStrLn ">>> Com1 <<<"
runCommand Com2 = putStrLn ">>> Com2 <<<"

opts :: ParserInfo Command
opts = info (commandParser <**> helper)
  $ fullDesc  
  <> progDesc "=== progDesc ==="
  <> header "=== header ==="
  <> footer "=== footer ==="

main :: IO ()
main = runCommand =<< execParser opts
```

When this program is run with neither command `com1` nor `com2` specified, a help message is displayed.

```
$ program
Missing: (COMMAND | COMMAND)

Usage: options-applicative-example-exe (COMMAND | COMMAND)
  === progDesc ===
```

This help message displays `(COMMAND | COMMAND)` instead of `(com1 | com2)`, and I think that specifying the names in this help message would be clearer and more useful.

Specifying the `--help` option as in `$ program --help` gives a different output.

```
$ program --help
=== header ===

Usage: options-applicative-example-exe (COMMAND | COMMAND)
  === progDesc ===

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text

Available commands:
  com1
  com2

=== footer ===
```

The command names `com1` and `com2` are listed in the "Available commands" section. Here too, however, I think the usage section would be clearer as `(com1 | com2)` instead of `(COMMAND | COMMAND)`.

**How can I specify the usage section of the help message to be `(com1 | com2)` instead of `(COMMAND | COMMAND)`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you can use `metavar` on the command.

```
com1 = subparser $ mconcat
  [ metavar c
  , command c $ info (pure Com1) fullDesc)
  ] where c = "com1"
```

Whereas here each command is its own subparser, the docs of `optparse-applicative` prefer to combine `command` modifiers first before applying `subparser` to the whole, so we would only see a single `COMMAND` and `metavar` wouldn't work well.

Comment: Thanks! I find it useful as well.

Comment: Applied your suggestions in this PR for `hs-init`: https://github.com/vrom911/hs-init/pull/43